# Undefined reference to static string vector

Tags: c++, oop

So I have this class:

```cpp
class Movie
{
    std::string name;
    std::string rating;
    size_t watched;
    static std::vector<std::string> vec;

public:
    Movie(std::string name, std::string rating, size_t watched)
    {
        this->name = name;
        this->rating = rating;
        this->watched = watched;
        std::cout << "Created movie " << this->name << std::endl;
        --> //vec.push_back(this->name);
    }

    static void dispAll() {
        --> //std::cout << "There are " << vec.size() << " movies: " << std::endl;
        --> //for(auto movie: vec){
          //cout << "Movie: " << movie.name << endl;
       //}
    }
};
```

And this is my main:

```cpp
int main(){
  Movie::dispNum();
  Movie saw("saw","PG-13",10);
  Movie::dispNum();

  return 0;
}
```

So what this class does is it just permits the user to create a Movie with this syntax `Movie("name","rating",watched_count)`, this class also contains a static vector and adds to it the name of the movie created in the constructor, the user can then access the dispNum function which returns the size of the vector that essentially shows the number of movies and then loops through the vector to display each movie, 
now when I try to access this vector on the lines with the arrow `-->` I get a linker error `main.cpp:(.text._ZN5MovieC2ENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES5_m[_ZN5MovieC2ENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES5_m]+0xce): undefined reference to 'Movie::vec[abi:cxx11]'`.

Any idea what could be wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside a `class` declaration, [`static` members](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static) are *declared*, but not *defined*.

You still need to *define* `static` members somewhere in your program.

For example like this

```
class Movie
{
    static std::vector<std::string> vec;   // declaration
};

std::vector<std::string> Movie::vec; // definition
```

Since C++17 you can declare it `inline`, in which case it will be defined inside the class:

```
class Movie
{
    inline static std::vector<std::string> vec;   // declaration and definition
};
```